# Windows 10 Sound Level Issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, sound-card, asus-laptop

After i move on the Windows 10 my sound level acting weird. For example my windows sound level is 20. When i open an audio (can from video player, audio player, browser etc. source doesn't matter) i hear sound loudly. Then when i change the windows main sound level to 21 for example then sound goes to normal level and i don't hear it so loudly. So to make my sound normal, i should go and increase windows main sound level 1 level higher or lower then it became OK.

I move on to windows 10 with a new PC so i don't now if my PC have a problem or windows 10. I don't even know if this is a feature or a bug.

So it this is a bug or feature? If this is a feature what it is called? How can disable it? If this is a windows bug how can i fix it? If this is a bug about my sound card what can i do the prevent it?

System Info: 
Windows 10 Pro x64 (1607), 
Asus N550JK-CN090H

Comment: It's not a feature. It may well be a driver issue - check for newer drivers from ASUS - Windows may not use the latest/best, ironically.

Comment: i am using Driver Booster to keep my drivers updated. So i have updated my driver many times but this behavior doesn't change. So i am highly suspicious about driver related issue.

Comment: Is this on all programs, or only some? I experienced this behavior today watching some flash content in my Chrome browser. Each time a new element loaded, the volume would go up substantially. Opening the volume slider and dragging the slider just down 1 mark and then back up would take the volume back down to a correct level. This with a RealTek audio device. I have not done any troubleshooting yet as this was the first time I'd noticed the issue.

Comment: yeah, it is on all programs. I believe mine also RealTek Audio Device. Even after i correct the level (increase a level and decrease again) if i stop the video and start it again then audio boost again so then i need to correct level again... So annoying.